# php mysql Get the latest records based on multiple conditions and count them

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have one table - staff

```
id | staff Name | adress
-------------------------
1 | Mr.A        | Any Address
2 | Mr. B       | Any Address
```

2nd Table - employment_history

```
eid | staff_id | school_id | type       | grade | date_of_appointmet
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 1         | 1        |Promotion   | 17    | 2012-12-12
2   | 1         | 2        |promotion   | 18    | 2013-2-2
3   | 2         | 2        |appointment | 17    | 2013-3-3
 and so on tables moves
```

Now the Question is that

- i want to get the latest job of the person with his details from the staff table
- how can i count how many of 17 grade staff works in school_id 1 
  (remembering that staff_id 1 (mr.a) now have been promoted to 18 and now works in school_id 2.)

Comment: Could you let us know what queries you've already tried?

Comment: if used what ever i remembered or searched like distinct(staff_id) on employment_history, inner joining and by applying Limit but could not get espically the 2nd part of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select staff_id, max(date_of_appointment) as date_of_appointment
from employment_history
group by staff_id
```

This query will return the most recent staff record for each staff_id.  Turn it into a subquery and join onto the employment history table

```
Select grade, count(1) 
from
(select staff_id, max(date_of_appointment) as date_of_appointment
from employment_history
group by staff_id) a
inner join employment_history e on e.staff_id = a.staff_id and a.date_of_appointment = e.date_of_appointment
 group by grade
```

This solution makes the assumption that staff_id + date_of_appointment is a unique key...if you have multiple rows where one staff_id has multiple employment history entries for one date, this won't work.  You need some logic to make the 'most recent employment history entry' return a unique combination of data...if staff_id + max(date_of_appointment) is not unique, you'll need to come up with logic in the 'a' subquery that returns unique data.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like

```
SELECT *
FROM employment_history eh1
WHERE eh1.date_of_employment = (
    SELECT max(eh2.date_of_employment)
    FROM staff s
    JOIN employment_history eh2 ON s.id = eh2.staff_id
    WHERE s.id = ?
)
```

Recplacing the `?`, or using `bind_param()` as appropriate.

Comment: thx jedwaards, i little modified the query to match more conditions with eh1 and it's working voilla!